# How can i change the unsorted icon for a rich:column?

Tags: jsf, seam, richfaces

Is there a way to change the default unsorted icon for a rich:column?

I am aware that you can add sortIcon="/images/myPic.png", but i don't want to have to add that for every single column.

I tried adding an attribute selector to my CSS file to "hide" the image:

```
img[src="/app/a4j/g/3_3_0.GAorg.richfaces.renderkit.html.iconimages.DataTableIconSortNone/DATB/eAFjYGD4!!8!AAYAAv4_"]
{
    width: 0px;
}
```

That works for Firefox, but IE doesn't honor it.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `sortIcon` attribute of the `rich:column` tag to point to your own image as in:

```
<rich:column sortIcon="img/defaultIcon.png">...</rich:column>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the RichFaces documentation:

> You can customize the sorting's icon
>   element using "rich-sort-icon" class

So I'd create a class in your css file that references the icon you'd like to use.

[RichFaces rich:column documentation](http://www.jboss.org/file-access/default/members/jbossrichfaces/freezone/docs/devguide/en/html/rich_column.html)

Comment: That's a good answer, and i forgot to mention that i tried that. Unfortunately all 3 states of sorting (unsorted, asc, desc) all get the same "rich-sort-icon" class. So if i change the properties for rich-sort-icon, it will change for all 3 states, not just unsorted.
Thanks though!